# jQuery - Set selected value of all dropdowns on page

Tags: jquery, selector

I have another jQuery question. For a user control with lots of database activity, I would like to use jQuery to set the selected values of all of the dropdowns to their "current" value. I want to do this to make the page appear to have finished the database call.

My jQuery skill is not the best, but I believe I need to use the pageLoad(). And since each dropdown is inside of a user control I can search for those dropdowns beginning with "usrControl"

```
$('select[id ^="usrControl"'].each(function(){ 
    var selectedValue = $(this).val()
    $(this).val(selectedValue)
});
```

Something like this is what I have in mind.

Thanks

Comment: The above would have no effect, since it would set the value to what it already is...can you be a bit more specific about what you're trying to set it to?

Comment: I have a parent->child relationship between dropdowns. When 'a' changes a database call is done to build 'b'. During this time the postback occurs and I would like to set the selected value of all dropdowns in the page to their prior selection if still available to avoid the annoying AJAX postback effect on the UI. I hope this is clear, I see the only way of doing this by setting the current selection of all drop downs on the page to their prior value whenever the page changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think an approach would be to save the default values of the sliders on page load. To accomplish this you can add data to the controls with the current value like:

```
$(selector).each(function() {
    $(this).data('default_val', $(this).val());
});
```

And after the database is updated you can 'reset' the values.

```
$(selector).each(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).data('default_val'));
});
```

You should change selector with the right selector ofc. :)

Perhaps it is also an idea to inform the user of a successful update. other then just restting the selects. Because I think it may be possible for users to submit using default values?

Check out this simple example @ jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lw7m8/

Comment: It should contain the selected value. Hold on I'll setup a jsFiddle.

Comment: It does, ok, I will try this approach. Thanks again, I appreciate it

Comment: Added a working example @ jsFiddle. Edited my answer. Follow link to check it out.